# Streaming video in an Apple TV TVJS app works in the simulator but fails on the device with an arcane error

Tags: apple-tv, tvml, tvjs

I am trying to stream video in a TVML app. Streaming the video works in the simulator, but on the device I get an arcane error message that doesn't explain anything.

I'm using the code from [this example](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/samplecode/TVMLAudioVideo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016506) with the below code changed in the function startPlayback(event) section.

```
var player = new Player();

player.playlist = new Playlist();

var video = new MediaItem('video', 'http://cdnapi.kaltura.com/p/1626222/sp/162622200/playManifest/entryId/0_eq9i2jbt/format/url/protocol/http/a.m3u8');
video.title = 'title';
video.subtitle = 'subtitle';
video.description = 'description';
video.artworkImageURL = 'artworkImageURL';

player.playlist.push(video);

setPlaybackEventListeners(player);

player.play();
```

Error Message:

> 2016-04-05 18:05:08.821 TeeVee[255:12143] #T:[Main] #Notice #SYSTEM :
>   Template controller: <_TVProductTemplateController: 0x12f021400> 
>   2016-04-05 18:05:14.298 TeeVee[255:12143] #T:[Main] #Error #SYSTEM :
>   Error occurred: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The
>   operation could not be completed"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x130519500 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16044 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16044),
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed} 
>   2016-04-05 18:05:14.298 TeeVee[255:12143] #T:[Main] #Error #SYSTEM :
>   Stopping due to error

Comment: Leaving work. I might not be able to test this on my home network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, it was an [AppTransport issue](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33). We're whitelisting our Kaltura domains, but I guess we're missing one. When I disable AppTransport completely, the app worked without error. I wish Apple would display the domain that's not whitelisted or https when the error occurs.